# Binary XML file line #587: Error inflating class ImageView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, kotlin

I have gone through multiple answers on StackOverflow but still not clear how to fix this crash.
I am getting this crash from Firebase,

> "Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException Unable to start activity
> ComponentInfo{com.Activity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML
> file line #587: Binary XML file line #587: Error inflating class
> ImageView"

enter code here

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_img" />
```

I am using a drawable image, I have kept images in all folders mdpi,hdpi,xdpi,xxhdpi,xxxhdpi. (And I am not using vector image). I have tried running my app on all resolution emulators not able to reproduce this crash but still seeing it in crashlytics very frequently. Happening majorly in samsung, oppo,Vivo.
Do i need to keep same image in a drawable folder as well if I am keeping them in drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi...folders.

Can anyone please help me with how to fix this crash?

Comment: Its better if you can share the xml file also.

Comment: Are you using "ic_img" drawable in "drawable" folder or "drawable-v24" folder? If you kept drawable img in "drawable-v24" folder then try copying that in "drawable" folder also. Because while compiling, compiler didnt find "drawable-v24" folder image, so its better if you copy and paste it in "drawable" folder.
Hope it will help!

Comment: it is in drawable-hdpi,drawable-mdpi,drawable-xhdpi,drawable-xxhdpi,drawable-xxxhdpi folder only, Is it required to keep image directly in drawable folder as well??

Comment: No its not required until or unless you correctly place the images in all the folders (drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-xhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi, drawable-xxxhdpi) or you are using the same name in each of them and also in your xml file.
The only thing you have to make sure that drawable images are not in "drawable-v24" folder only. It should be in "drawable" folder also.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same problem. Try the steps below, it may also work for you:

1. Rename the drawable name.
2. update the drawable name in the image view.
3. Clean and rebuild the project.
4. Run the app.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this crash at my end, any i crash report i am seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your drawable image was inside of drawable-v24. If it is move it to drawable folder

Comment: all drawable images are in drawable-ldpi,drawable-mdpi,drawable-hdpi,drawable-xhdpi..so on, folders.

Comment: i am keep on seeing this crash in crashlytics only not happening at my end.